# how to set up outbound email on a fresh server?

Tags: email, debian

I'm a novice when it comes to server admin, and I need some help. I recently got sick of GoDaddy, and I signed up for an unmanaged rackspace server. I'm running a Debian instance, and I'd like to set up the server to send outgoing email via PHP and via cron.

PHP and Apache are already installed. I've installed sendmail, via apt. I have no idea how to set any of this up. I don't really need inbound support, although I imagine it would be nice for my PHP emails. (Or I can just have `sendmail()` change the return address in my PHP script.)

Specifically, I have no idea how to configure sendmail as an outgoing mail server. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the default sendmail config on Debian allows outbound relaying, and listens on 127.0.0.1 by default - pretty much the config you need.

Try testing with something like this:

```
root@test1:~# mail outside-address@example.com
Subject: test
asdf
.
```

..and check if the listener is working:

```
netcat localhost 25
```

If the message works outbound, then you should be in good shape.

For cron, the email is send to the user that owns the job; if you want those messages going outbound, set up an alias for the user the cron is running under in `/etc/aliases`.

For PHP, you should be able to configure the application to point to localhost, port 25, and have it successfully send mail outside.

Comment: Ok, so sending via the mail command works. How would I configure aliases?

Comment: Say you wanted mail bound for the `root` user to go to `someone@gmail.com`.  Add a line to `/etc/aliases` like this: `root: someone@gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

Start with a guide, such as http://www.wikihow.com/Configure-Sendmail. Or google other guides, find one you can follow, go through the steps and read the readme files.

Heres a better one http://frenchtouch.pro/tutorial/configure-your-debian-server-to-send-mails/47

Comment: We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.